# Django redirect to root from a view

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

I am creating a django project. However, I have come across a small hiccup. My urls.py looks like this

```
url(r'^login/(?P<nextLoc>)$', 'Home.views.login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'Home.views.logout'),
```

My views.py in the Home app is as follows:

```
def login(request,nextLoc):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        user=auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect(nextLoc)
            else:
                error='This account has been disabled by the administrator. Contact the administrator for enabling the said account'
        else:
            error='The username/password pair is incorrect. Check your credentials and try again.'

    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect("/profile/")
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        error=''
    return render_to_response('login.html',{'FORM':form,'ERROR':error},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

Now when I am going to the login page, it is opening up as expected. After I submit the form, I get an error that says that it can't find the module urls. After digging around a bit, I noticed that the redirect("/") actually translates into `http://localhost/login/` instead of `http://localhost/`. The same happens in logout, i.e. it tries opening the url `http://localhost/logout/` instead of `http://localhost/`. Basically, when the page opened is `http://localhost/login`, the `redirect('/')` adds the / to the end of the current url, and voila - I get a url that I didn't expect - `http://localhost/login/`. I cannot get it to redirect to the root of the site using the redirect.

Please help me out with this and if possible also explain the cause of this irrational behavior of Django

Comment: Did you try HttpResponseRedirect ?

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def logout(request):
 return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

Comment: where's the rest of your urls.py? What view corresponds to "/" ?

Answer (score 15):

I am using Django 3.1. This is what I do to achieve this:

in `urls.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns = [
    path('', lambda req: redirect('/myapp/')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

Comment: this works well, but could you please explain how it works?
specifically, why doesn't it work if i only use redirect, without the lambda
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [documentation for redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), there are several things you can pass to the function:

- A model
- A view name
- A URL

In general, I think it's better to redirect to a view name rather than a URL. In your case, assuming your urls.py has an entry that looks something like:

```
url(r'^$', 'Home.views.index'),
```

I would instead use redirect like this:

```
redirect('Home.views.index')
```

Comment: jterrace is right, since you are using `url()` you can `name` it  `url(r'^$','Home.views.index',name="home_index")` and use it in the view as `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_index'))` also use it in the template with the `<a href={% url home_index %}>home</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Also complementing Ken Cloud answer, if you have named urls you can just call the url name:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns = [
    path('app/', include('myapp.urls'), name='app')
    path('', lambda req: redirect('app')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```