# Django URLS, how to map root to app?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am pretty new to django but experienced in Python and java web programming with different frameworks.
I have made myself a nice little django app, but I cant seem to make it match www.mysite.com as opposed to www.mysite.com/myapp.

I have defined urls and views in my urls.conf which is currently not decoupled from the app (don't mind that).

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
  (r'^myapp/$', 'index'),
  (r'^myapp/(?P<some_id>\d+)/global_stats/$', 'global_stats'),
  (r'^myapp/(?P<some_id>\d+)/player/(?P<player_id>\d+)/$', 'player_stats'),
)
```

All this works like a charm. If someone goes to www.mysite.com/myapp they will hit my index view which causes a http redirect to my "correct" default url.

So, how can I add a pattern that will do the same as (r'^myapp/$', 'index') but without the /myapp--that is, www.mysite.com should suffice?

I would think this would be very basic stuff... I tried adding a line like:

```
(r'^$', 'index'),
```

however this throws me in a loop...

Hope you django gurus out there can clarify this for me!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This sounds strange.

Your latest attempt should work, but what I normally do - put

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', lambda r: HttpResponseRedirect('myapp/')),
    ...
)
```

This scales better when you start adding new apps.

Comment: Well, for some reason this works, and my solution doesn't - so ill stick with this!! :)

Comment: if you send me gzip with your minimal app I can see what's wrong with it. BTW, from my different file: urlpatterns = patterns('common.views', url('^$', 'home', name='home'), ...), works just fine

Comment: This is extremely good, as it ensures the user ends up at the real/'correct' URL for the app, rather than silently implying it's really located at the root.

Comment: In Django 2.1 this no longer seems to work.  I get the error "ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern ('^$', <function <lambda> at 0x0000000004E5A510>) is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of path() and/or re_path() instances.  HINT: Try using path() instead of a tuple."  I changed it to path('', lambda r: HttpResponseRedirect('cl/')), and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 105):

I know that this question was asked 2 years ago, but I've faced the same problem and found a solution:

In the project `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('my_app.urls')), #NOTE: without $
)
```

In `my_app.urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'my_app.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^v1/$', 'my_app.views.v1', name='name_1'),
    url(r'^v2/$', 'my_app.views.v2', name='name_2'),
    url(r'^v3/$', 'my_app.views.v3', name='name_3'),
)
```

Comment: Great! Works on django 1.8

Comment: PERFECT! Works like a charm with Django 1.8.4

Comment: To reference root in a page:

         <a href="{% url 'my_app:home' %}">Start page</a>

Comment: yeaay,, i just found your command. Thank you. In my case :



`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^reportsys/', views.index, name='index'),
#    url(r'^index/', views.index, name='index'),
#    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^dataprocessing/', views.dataprocessing, name='dataprocessing'),
]`

Answer (score 30):

As I didn't see any answer for django 2.0 I thought I'll provide one. you have to use `''` as the root url. Here is an example from [django 2.0 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', main_views.homepage),
    path('help/', include('apps.help.urls')),
    path('credit/', include(extra_patterns)),
]
```

Comment: If you want to redirect (like in the accepted answer by @Guard), you may also use `RedirectView.as_view(url='myapp/')`. In the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

Answer (score 7):

old question here ...  (as much as myself :o)
but still worth of  sharing  updates for Django 3.x:

In project urls.py  just add:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')), 
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Be aware that this solution will monopolize the whole django to your hungry&selfish app :-) !!!

Comment: This is a good solution for Django 4. Better than using the redirect as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63333822/6552114

Answer (score 5):

Just put an empty raw regular expression: r''

I tested here and it worked perfectly.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('homepage.urls')),
    url(r'^homepage/', include('homepage.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Hope it help!

Comment: any urls generated from helpers in the template don't work if you do it this way :(

Comment: What file did you update that in? Not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

I also wanted to have the root of my domain to directly point to a view of a sub app.

At first I created the sub app with this command:

```
python3 manage.py startapp main offer_finder/main
```

In your case it would be:

```
python3 manage.py startapp myApp project/somedirectory/myApp
```

make sure that the directory exists: `mkdir -p project/somedirectory/myApp`

This is my project structure: [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz4Hy.png)

In my case I have these directories:

```
offer_finder_project/offer_finder/main        # sub app  
offer_finder_project/offer_finder/            # main source directory
```

in `offer_finder_project/offer_finder/urls.py` I have this code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('offer_finder.main.urls')),
]
```

And in `offer_finder_project/offer_finder/main/urls.py` I have this code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

And the `offer_finder_project/offer_finder/main/views.py` file simply contains some test code.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("TEST app index")
```

This way your requests to your root domain are directed to your sub app.
Hopefully this helps someone.
This code was tested with Django 2.1.4.

Comment: This is the cleaner solution for Django3 as well. Why are the other answers using regex and not following documentation (if i read it correctly)?

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer is late, but i had my fair share of hunting recently. This is what i tried with CBV..
in Project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('app_name.urls', namespace='app_name')),
]
```

PS: It is always recommended to use namespace. Gives a good advantage later on.

In App urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexPageView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Comment: re_path() is now preferred for regexes instead of url() as url() will be deprecated. path() can be used where regexes are not required