# Why Django base URL can't be reached?

Tags: python, django, url

I am having trouble accessing the base url for my django app once it is deployed.

Can't reach base url:

> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

This just runs until it times out.

Can reach:

> www.example.com/home/

Here are my allowed hosts in settings.py:

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'example' 'https://example.com/', '127.0.0.1']

Here are my url patterns in myapp/urls.py:

> from .views import index

> urlpatterns = [
> path('', index, name='index'),
> path('home/', index, name="index"),
> ]

I have tried adjusting the url patterns but have had no success. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

root urls.py:

> urlpatterns = [
> path('', include('myapp.urls')),
> path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
> ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

Change your allowed hosts to

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'www.example.com', '127.0.0.1']
```

Comment: Hmmm..no luck with that format. What else am I missing potentially?

Comment: can you share your root `urls.py` file?

Comment: Added above. I have tried some solutions in this link to no avail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580220/django-urls-how-to-map-root-to-app

Comment: Need to add '/home/' path to URLconf