# Getting character error when posting with form

Tags: django

Does anybody ever experienced error like this? When I tried to login with form, and check the data from mysql, I got the error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://tesmyapp.loc/post/login/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
near "����������": **syntax error**
Exception Location: /myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py in _quote_params_for_last_executed_query, line 129
Python Executable:  /myapp/env/bin/uwsgi
```

I'm not sure this is error from mysql, because when I tried to post without checking database, the error still appears

function in views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def post_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get("username", "")
        password = request.POST.get("password", "")
        mylogin = check_login(username, password)
        if mylogin > 0:
            occur = "success"
            request.session['member'] = username
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")
```

If someone had facing this error, please share the solution. thanks

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://tesmyapp.loc/post/login/

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'login']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  235.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  50.                         request.session.save()

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in save
  80.             return self.create()

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in create
  49.             self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in _get_new_session_key
  158.             if not self.exists(session_key):

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in exists
  45.         return self.model.objects.filter(session_key=session_key).exists()

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in exists
  651.             return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in has_results
  501.         return compiler.has_results()

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in has_results
  819.         return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  848.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  83.             sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py" in last_executed_query
  140.                 params = self._quote_params_for_last_executed_query(params)

File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py" in _quote_params_for_last_executed_query
  129.             return cursor.execute(sql, params).fetchone()

Exception Type: OperationalError at /login
Exception Value: near "����������": syntax error
```

python manage.py migrate :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 89, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you post complete stack trace?

Comment: I just edited my question @Siva thanks for respond

Comment: Given that the stacktrace doesn't include views.py, I'm wondering whether you got this error in other places, e.g. when doing a `> python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: I just realized I cannot doing migrate, my question updated with the errors @raphv

Comment: Can you make sure that your model and table names only use ASCII characters. Also, if you use special characters in your file (e.g. for the verbose names), can you make sure you add the right encoding headers to your file? `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: What view does `"/home"` correspond to? Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284952/django-redirect-to-root-from-a-view ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with change database from sqlite to mysql