# Redirecting to root URL from another app's view

Tags: django

I am trying to redirect to root URL when an app's URL is accessed without the user being logged-in.

I've tried to do so in 2 ways:

1. Using a decorator

```
@login_required(login_url = '')
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'professors/index.html')
```

> Which returned a 404 error saying the current path is `accounts/login`

2. Passing the `views` of the root page to `redirect`

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'professors/index.html')
    else:
        return redirect('login.views.index')
```

> Which returned a 404 error saying the current path is `professors/login.views.index`

The root URL is `localhost:8000/` and I am trying to redirect to it after accessing `localhost:8000/professors/` when the user is not logged-in.

This problem is similar to what I've found here: [Django redirect to root from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284952/django-redirect-to-root-from-a-view)

However, applying the solution did not work for me. It looks like when redirecting to root from an app's view, the root it is redirecting to is the app's root, and not the website's, and this is true for any URL redirected after accessing an app's URL. E.g., if the root URL is `localhost:8000` and the app's URL is `localhost:8000/professors/`, then trying to access any other URL from the latter, will mean that `localhost:8000/professors/` is the starting point and what I write in the `login_url` or `redirect(redirect_URL)` is added to that, which means that I can no longer access `localhost:8000`

Final note:

When I tried `return redirect ('')` in `else` it returned

> NoReverseMatch at /professors/
>
> Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
>   Which shows that the starting point is again from `localhost:800/professors/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your **`login_url`** parameter in [**`login_required` decorator**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator),

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'professors/index.html')
```

---

You can also set the [**`LOGIN_URL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#login-url) in **`settings`**

```
#settings.py
LOGIN_URL='/'
```

Comment: Thank you! It does redirect to main page, but the URL shown is ```http://localhost:8000/?next=/professors/``` instead of ```http://localhost:8000```, any idea why is that? Also, why does redirecting does not work?

Comment: It's the `redirect_field_name`. When you authenticate from the root url, Django will take you to **`/professors/`**, which is the URL you were trying to access in first place.

Comment: Was willing to, had to wait few minutes before I could. Then, I have to use the decorator for redirection? In other words, without the decorator I cannot go "back" in the URL?

Comment: ^ (I think you viewed the comment before I was able to edit it)

Comment: Yeah.. You are right. You can't go back to the URL without that decorator.